# CSS font-feature-settings for textView?

Tags: android

can we use css font-feature-settings in text View?
add friction like 1/2 and other properties of font-feature-settings.

Answer (score 3):

A good example and explanation found here.sorry for bad english. http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/11/android-stacked-fractions.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=22c3800806-Android_Weekly_130&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-22c3800806-337885537

```
   Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
    getAssets(), "Nutso2.otf");
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    textView.setText("1/2 2/5");
    textView.setFontFeatureSettings("afrc");
```

Comment: This looks promising. Can you answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539237/supporting-complex-text-layout-with-opentype-fonts-in-android